# How can I get a full backtrace out of assets precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sprockets

I have an error when compiling my assets, but rake or sprockets or something in the stack is swallowing it

```
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
uninitialized constant #<Class:0x007fae6cb3dd88>::FooBar
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/john/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p385-per...]
```

How can I get more detail? I am running rake with `--trace --verbose`

Comment: Have you searched for the constant it claims is undefined?

Comment: I don't need help debugging this particular problem, I would just like  rake to show backtraces. I figured out where in rake the exception is being swallowed and made this ticket: https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/189